# How to add a new menu/submenu page in WPMVC?

Tags: mvc

I'm completely new to [WPMVC](http://wpmvc.org/). Followed and finished their tutorial for creating plugins. Now I'm trying to add a search page to search `Venues` (that comes from their example!). This page should appear as a submenu page of the `Venues` menu. I created a file named `search.php` in the `app/views/admin/venue/search` folder. What should I do now? Googling didn't help much!

Any help regarding this (and any other stuff a noob should learn to get better with WPMVC) is welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Finally after a lot of digging into the core files, I found the way to add a `submenu` page. Here's the stepwise solution if anyone is stuck on it!

Lets assume you want to add a submenu page called 'Sample'.

1.First, in the `app/config/bootstrap.php` file (you have to manually create it if it doesn't exist) of your plugin, add the following code. This will add the new page as a `submenu` of the `venues` parent menu item:

```
<?php
//sample is appended to the venues array, meaning it will be a submenu page of venues
MvcConfiguration::append(array(
'AdminPages' => array(
    'venues' => array(
        'add',
        'delete',
        'edit',
        'sample'
        )
    )
));
?>
```

2.Next, in the `app/controllers/admin/admin_venues_controller.php` add the following function. Notice it is named `sample`, same as the page name in the array above.

```
function sample() {
    //this array will be available as $values in the sample.php file
    $vals = array('great' => 'Done', 'nice' => 'Finally');
    $this->set('values', $vals);
}
```

3.Now the actual page content file, create a `sample.php` (notice the name) file in the `app/views/admin/venues/` folder.

```
<?php
    echo '<h2>'.MvcInflector::titleize($this->action).'</h2>';
    //remember the values variable set in the controller? 
    foreach($values as $i => $val){ ?>
        echo $i.' = '.$val;
    }
?>
```

That's pretty much it! I'm still stuck on creating a top level menu page without having to create a model (models get top level pages by default). Will update this answer when I solve it!

Note: Emailing Tom Benner, the creator of WPMVC didn't help too! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add an action hook in your plugin main file `plugin_name.php`, giving the details of the menu. You can have an admin menu, of course, without generating a model.

Here is the code for `/plugins/my-plugin/my_plugin.php`

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_custom_menu_page' );    
function my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page( 
        'My Menu', 
        'My Menu', 
        'manage_options', 
        'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php', 
        '', 
        plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 
        6 
    );
}
```

You can leave the image location empty to use a default WordPress icon for the custom menu.

Of course, you can add submenus in the same way, or using `bootstrap.php` as well.

In the picture below, I have added 'My Menu' by this method.

[image]